# PHP - execution time limit

Tags: php

Order task on per image.

```
- check image exist
- create thumbnail
- save information of images and thumb to database
```

If we do it with very more images and need more time to execute request than default of php (30s)

Does the time contain php execution time + mysql time ? or only time for php ?

When i save information ,some images missing infor when still insert to database

example : with 30 images

```
php : scan information of 25 images 
mysql: insert 30 images infor
```

i think php process time exceed to default time , request will be stop. so mysql only insert 25 images infor. That right ?

```
$infor 

if (// create thumb and get infor successfull) // if exceed time , why script don't stop inserting infor
{
   $infor return information of images
}

$database->insert($infor)
```

what i want to know is when script will be stop. if process is create thumb step and be stopped by exceed time, why script continue insert null infor to database

Comment: Possibly. Why don't you increase the time limit and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: what i want to know is when script will be stop

Comment: The script will not continue to insert null data to a database after it has stopped, or it's not stopped. If you are getting null data in your database it's because your code is wrong.

Comment: I'm checking my code....

Answer (score 1):

You can increase time in .ini files or code like this

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Or use set_time_limit function on PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: what i want to know is when script will be stop. if process is create thumb step and be stopped by exceed time, why script continue insert null infor to database

Answer (score 0):

in such cases use

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

0 means unlimited .
Use this function on top of your php file which can take long time .